# Google auto complete address form on page load

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

I have been following this example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform which shows how to have a field that implements the auto complete dropdown with Google maps, and then when the user selects an address to fill out the individual form elements (Like street name etc..).

The address field will already be filled out in my case though so I just need to fill out the form elements when the page loads using this address.

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    fillInAddress();
});
```

To force it on start but the form elements stay empty. Does any one have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing only `fillInAddress();` might not be enough, you have to do something with the `autocomplete` too. However, since it is not open source or mentioned anywhere in the docs, there seems to be no way to do that.

One work around would be to use the Places web service API to get the same info. For more information about that please refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details).

Comment: Thanks kaho, I used further places api to retrieve the relevant information by using the long/lat data.